# If $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable, are $f\cdot g$ and $f/g$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I do not think they are, but I cannot seem to come up with a definitive answer. I have tried using the "Cauchy criterion" for integrability $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$$
Here, $U(f,P)$ is the upper Darboux sum and $L(f,P)$ is the lower Darboux sum. For $f\cdot g$, I have tried using $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\sqrt\varepsilon$$ $$U(g,P)-L(g,P)<\sqrt\varepsilon$$
But I am not getting anywhere. I am not quite sure what to do for the $\frac{f}{g}$.
**Edit:** For $\frac{f}{g}$, $g\neq0$

Comment: I think you need a guarantee that $f\over g$ is bounded, or that $g$ is non-zero...

Comment: Which concept of integrability? Riemann? Lebesgue? Something else?

Comment: I am dealing with Darboux Integrability which is equivalent to Riemann Integrability. I think.

Comment: @abiessu, is requiring $g$ to be non-zero sufficient? What if it approaches zero somewhere even though it's never zero?

Comment: $fg$ is Riemann integrable. $f/g$ is, provided that it is bounded. The assumption that $g\ne0$ is not enough to ensure this. If we know that for some $\epsilon>0$, $|g(x)|>\epsilon$ for all $x$ in its domain, then $f/g$ is integrable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $f,g$ are both Riemann integrable, then $f\cdot g$ is. This follows by proving that if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $f^2$ is, then using $2fg=(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2$. But we have that $|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|\leqslant 2M|f(x)-f(y)|$ where $M$ is an upper bound for $f$ over the interval in quastion. If $g$ is bounded away from zero, then $f/g$ will be Riemann integrable, for the oscillation of $1/g$ is no greater than that of $g$ times a constant, namely if $g\geqslant m>0$  $$\left|\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{g(y)}\right|=\left|\frac{g(x)-g(y)}{g(x)g(y)}\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{m^2}|g(x)-g(y)|$$

Comment: Assuming we have already proved that the sum of Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable, and since the expression of $fg$ is can be written as a composition of sums and squares of Riemann integrable functions, isn't that enough to conclude immediately that $fg$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Carlyle You still need to prove that the square of a RI function is also RI.

Comment: Yes, I meant after you have proven that as well, I was confused as to why there was more to the answer, but I see now it might be for the next part of the question

Answer (score 7):

It suffices to prove the statement: if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then so is $f^2$, then $fg = \dfrac 1 2((f + g)^2 - f^2 - g^2) $is integrable. To show that $f^2$ is integrable use the following:

So: $$\begin{align}U(f^2, P) - L(f^2,P) &= \sum (M_i^2 - m_i^2)\Delta x_i \\&< 2T \sum (M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i\\&= 2T(U(f,P) - L(f,P)) \\&<2T\frac{\varepsilon }{2T} = \varepsilon\end{align}$$

Here $T = \sup\limits_{[a,b]} f(x)$. So $f^2$ is integrable.

Comment: Why you can affirm that f is bounded?

Comment: This assumes that $f+g$ is Riemann integrable.  Does this need proof?

Answer (score -1):

İf $f$ and $g$ are integrable in given interval, then they are bounded also. So, $fg$ is integrable also, because $|fg|< M|g|$ or $|fg|<N|f|$ for some positive constants $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> I'm not following the argument: If $M$ is real, $g$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, and $h$ is a function satisfying $|h| \leq M|g|$ on $[a, b]$, then $h$ need not be integrable on $[a, b]$...?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).